# How can I write an SQL query with this database design

Tags: sql

I have the following design:

[image]

A Juvenile can be a member but  it needs to belong to an Adult.

Now what if I want to write an SQL query to retrieve the Juvenile's full name and the Adult's full name it belongs to since the names for both are store in the same "Members" table ?

Comment: MemberNo is the primary key in three tables?

Comment: In this example, yes it is.

Comment: Actually, the FirstName LastName, MiddleInitial details belong only to Juveniles and, respectively, to Adults. These details belong to a person. On the other hand, in Members you would have only the id of each person (juvenile or adult) along with his/her member status, subscription date, last enrollment payment, etc. I don't know what you mean by Photograph. A members photo? If yes, then it belongs to Members indeed, because it's the photo uploaded especially for the membership. The other details though are not membership's dependent, as said.

Comment: In the new context it will be easy then to find Adult's, resp. Juvenile's name (or whatever details you need to fetch from the tables).

Comment: All you need is a members table. Dump Adults and Juveniles.

Comment: And MemberNo should in no way be primary key except in Members. Adults should have AdultId and Juveniles should have JuvenileId as PK fields. And no MemberNo field at all.

Comment: @nicomp I do not think so because a Juvenile needs to have his own account but his account needs to be related to an Adult because a Juvenile cannot rent a book without having an Adult attached to his/her's account.

Comment: @neilnm You can have a foreign key that references the same table it appears in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select M1.LastName, M1.FirstName,M2.LastName, M2.FirstName 
From Juveniles J 
   join Members M1 on J.MemberNo = M1.MemberNo
   join Adults A on J.AdultMemberNo = A.MemberNo
   join Members M2 on A.MemberNo = M2.MemberNo
 Where J.MemberNo = 1;
```

First name is juvenile's name and second name is Adult's name.

Comment: That worked greate, you can also do this to return all records:         
`Where J.MemberNo = M1.MemberNo`